# Get attachment URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I am attempting to grab the uploaded audio file from WordPress but having some issues. I need to grab the patch excluding the domain name so something like `wp-content/uploads/2014/09/file.mp3`.

I tried to use `get_attached_media()` and I can see exactly what I need when I `var_dump()` it is stored in an array with the key of `guid`. I have tried several different ways but I cannot access it. This is the result.

```
object(WP_Post)#2059 (24) {
 ["ID"]=>
 int(4312)
 ["post_author"]=>
 string(1) "3"
 ["post_date"]=>
 string(19) "2014-10-06 15:33:16"
 ["post_parent"]=>
 int(4298)
 ["guid"]=>
 string(73) "/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/file.mp3"

 }
}
```

I removed most of the code to keep it brief. How can I access the `guid` key? I store the results in `$a` and tried `$a->guid` `$a['guid']`and `$a->post->guid` and others but no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try something like `$a[0]->guid;` where 0 is the index of the array element ?

Comment: if `$a` is the object you var_dumped, then `$a->guid` should have worked. I'm guessing you missed something there. Also, the guid field is not actually reliable in all cases. I'd use `get_permalink` instead and then extract the required portion of the path.

Comment: Check this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110785/getting-a-specific-value-out-of-array-using-get-attached-media

Comment: Try: `wp_get_attachment_url($a->ID);`

Comment: For some reason I cannot access anything in the `$a` variable. I can just `var_dump($a)` as a whole. Anything else results to null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the documentation of the [get_attached_media](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_media) function you will see that it returns an array of [WP_Post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) objects.

The array is indexed by attachment id so you can't access the first element simply by doing `$a[0]`. I would recommend that you reindex the array before using it, like this:

```
$a = get_attached_media(...);
$a = array_values($a);
echo 'GUID: ' . $a[0]->guid;
```

You could also iterate over all the attachments like this

```
foreach ($a as $attachment) {
    echo "GUID: {$attachment->guid}\n";    
}
```

Comment: @JuanRangel I have updated the answer to show how this would work outside an foreach loop