# "wp_get_attachment_url" not working within functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

This works just fine in any other post:

```
$vid_att = get_attached_media('video',$post_id); // Check if a video is attached
// print_r($vid_att);
if ($vid_att) {
$vid_att_url = wp_get_attachment_url($vid_att->ID);
echo $vid_att_url;
}
```

HOWEVER

if I use this within my functions.php file it will return the full array (print_r($vid_att);) but will not return the ID when requested!

If I insert the attachment ID manually it works:

```
$vid_att_url = wp_get_attachment_url('138');
```

What can it be? I've tried converting ID to Integer and other stuff but cannot get it to work. Also ne errors given.

The array it returns looks like this:

```
Array ( [138] => WP_Post Object ( [ID] => 138 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2018-08-14 16:21:42 [post_date_gmt] => 2018-08-14 16:21:42 [post_content] => [post_title] => SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => inherit [comment_status] => open [ping_status] => closed [post_password] => [post_name] => samplevideo_1280x720_1mb [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2018-08-14 16:21:42 [post_modified_gmt] => 2018-08-14 16:21:42 [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 113 [guid] => http://flockstock/wp-content/uploads/edd/2018/08/SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mp4 [menu_order] => 0 [post_type] => attachment [post_mime_type] => video/mp4 [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) )
```

Comment: Err, `wp_get_attachment_url()` returns a [string or a boolean](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url), where is that array coming from?

Comment: I’m on my phone so can’t test this but $vid_att->ID implies $vid_att is an object but it’s an array (with an object as the first item) so might it be something like $vid_att[0]->ID ?

Comment: @BenM - print_r($vid_att); is returning the array that contains all the attachments info. But when I then try to access the URL using ID it won't do it.

Comment: Or $vid_att[$post_id]->ID

Comment: @wkille I already tried that, the weird thing is this works with exactly the same array retrieved in other posts with the same code. Could it be something to do with the fact it is within functions.php? Perhaps its not the same scope? Ive tried declaring the vars as global etc but no joy. really pulling hair out now!

Comment: Does the accepted answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26680817/get-attachment-url help?

Comment: @wkille BRILLIANT! YES that works ;)

    $vid_att = array_values($vid_att);
    echo 'GUID: ' . $vid_att[0]->guid;

Note:

wp_get_attachment_url($vid_att); still doesn't work within functions.php even if you reindex the array.

Still, I wonder why it works without this in my other posts.

Anyhow, thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conclusion:

```
$vid_att = get_attached_media('video',$post_id); // Check if a video is attached

    if ($vid_att) {

            $vid_att_arr = array_values($vid_att);
            $vid_att_ID = $vid_att_arr[0]->ID;
            $vid_att_url = wp_get_attachment_url($vid_att_ID);
            // echo $vid_att_url;
        }else{
            echo 'No Video uploaded!';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare the super variable before like that :

```
global $post;
echo $post->ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @wkille for pointing to this post where the answer lies:
[Get attachment URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26680817/get-attachment-url)

reindex the array before using it:

```
$vid_att = array_values($vid_att);
echo 'GUID: ' . $vid_att[0]->guid;
```

Note:

```
wp_get_attachment_url($post_id->ID);
```

still doesn't work within functions.php even if you reindex the array but it does work in posts, anyone know why this is?

Comment: I’m glad if I’ve been able to help! But two things, did you try echo 'ID: ' . $vid_att[0]->ID; ? I understand that using the guid for getting the url is considered a bit hacky. And in your note do you mean $vid_att->ID rather than $post_id->ID, and should that now be $vid_att[0]->ID after reindexing the array?

Comment: @wkille

yes i had tried echoing everything but to no avail, it seems the array is just not accessible due to it being indexed by the attachment ID itself as was explained by the answer in the link you sent.

Regarding the GUID - As far as i can see when you look at the returned array, thats the ONLY reference there is to the file url so WP must use that itself surely?

Yes, in my Note I intentionally put "$post_id" rather than "$vid_att" because that would be the common way to use wp_get_attachment_url. Sos for confusion.

Comment: Just found out this works too:
    $vid_att_url = wp_get_attachment_url($vid_att_arr[0]->ID);